# Why are textboxes being given focus when I click on buttons that are above it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, mxml, flex-mobile

I've got an mxml view, with a button in the actionContent and a viewMenu with two buttons.

In the main content I have a scroller and a vgroup, within which are a few textboxes, labels and buttons.

If I click on any of these 3 buttons when a textbox (TextInput or TextArea) is below them I end up focussing on the textbox rather than firing the click even of the button.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this a common thing, because I couldn't find anything about it searching google or here.

Btw, testing has been done with a physical iPad (1 and 2) and iPhone 4, as well as the emulated iPhone 4S and HTC Wildfire.

Comment: The behavior is definitely not common, so you need to show some code. From your description alone it'll be quite hard to help you.

Comment: @Al_Birdy thanks so much for your comment, I never received any notification or I would've replied. I feel very rude now. It's been a while since I touched this project, I should be getting back to it in the next week or so. When I do I'll take a look at what's happening (I can barely remember, I've had my head in some c# windows services more recently) and update this question with some code.